# jQuery jeditable Cannot read property 'plugin' of undefined when Trying to use datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, datetimepicker, jeditable

I have inherited a piece of code which originally only required an editiable date and this was implemented using jquery [datatables](https://datatables.net/), [jquery-editable](https://github.com/victorjonsson/jquery-editable) and [datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

this is the current working code for date only

```
$('.editdate')
    .editable(function (value, settings) {
    if ((value == null) || (value == '')) {
        return ($(this)
            .parent()
            .find('label')
            .text());
    }
    hasBeenEdited(this);
    return (value);
}, {
    type: 'datepicker',
    datepicker: {
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    }
});
```

Now I have been asked to include a time with the date (the data base & model on the serverside were changed to timestamp) and I am trying to incorperate the [datetimepicker](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon) addon.

When I do it outside of editable using `$(".editdatetime").datetimepicker()` it works as expected but when I try to do it using the editable function I get the following errors

```
firefox: TypeError: $.editable.types[settings.type] is undefined

chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugin' of undefined
```

this is my editable for `datetimepicker`

```
$('.editdatetime')
    .editable(function (value, settings) {
    if ((value == null) || (value == '')) {
        return ($(this)
            .parent()
            .find('label')
            .text());
    }
    hasBeenEdited(this);
    return (value);
}, {
    type: 'datetimepicker',
    datetimepicker: {
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showHour: true,
        showMinute: true
    }
});
```

Any guidance or help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

So I finally realised that I needed to add the input type `datetimepicker` to editable. So I managed to solve this using the following:

```
$.editable.addInputType( 'datetimepicker', {

    /* create input element */
element: function (settings, original) {
    var form = $(this),
        input = $('<input />');
    input.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    form.append(input);
    return input;
},

/* attach jquery.ui.datetimepicker to the input element */
plugin: function (settings, original) {
    var form = this,
        input = form.find("input");

    // Don't cancel inline editing onblur to allow clicking datetimepicker
    settings.onblur = 'nothing';

    datetimepicker = {
        onSelect: function () {
            // clicking specific day in the calendar should
            // submit the form and close the input field
            form.submit();
        },

        onClose: function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (!input.is(':focus')) {
                    // input has NO focus after 150ms which means
                    // calendar was closed due to click outside of it
                    // so let's close the input field without saving
                    original.reset(form);
                } else {
                    // input still HAS focus after 150ms which means
                    // calendar was closed due to Enter in the input field
                    // so lets submit the form and close the input field
                    form.submit();
                }

                // the delay is necessary; calendar must be already
                // closed for the above :focus checking to work properly;
                // without a delay the form is submitted in all scenarios, which is wrong
            }, 150);
        }
    };

    if (settings.datetimepicker) {
        jQuery.extend(datetimepicker, settings.datetimepicker);
    }

    input.datetimepicker(datetimepicker);
}
});
```